# Why this question was bumped

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question

Why was this question bumped to home page?

[Disable notification sounds but keep SMS Sounds](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/50100/disable-notification-sounds-but-keep-sms-sounds)

It has:

- 0 vote, 6+ years old question,
- 0 vote, 6+ years old single answer,
- no visual activity since then (though header says: *Active **today***).

In addition, this particular question is completely worthless (VTC?) today, six years after posting, because today's version of Android solves this particular problem (disabling notifications per application) natively, with system tools / system configuration.

And I quite strongly doubt that there is any significant number of Galaxy Ace Duos 6802 or Android 2.3 Gingerbread still out there.

So, frankly saying, there are two questions here: Why was this question bumped and why isn't it closed (should be close question that seems worthless in current days?)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question was automatically and randomly bumped by a Stack Exchange bot, [the Community user](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=profile).

> Hi, I'm not really a person.
>
> I'm a background process that helps keep this site clean!
>
> I do things like
>
> - Randomly poke old unanswered questions* every hour so they get some attention
> - [...]

The criteria for the [eligible questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19739) are

> Questions with at least 30 days of no activity, at least one answer scoring zero, and no answers scoring above that. Questions that are locked or closed will not be bumped. The Community User will only bump a maximum of one question per hour.

The objective of the random bump is to let anyone notice and review the Q&A and see if there's any action that can be taken:

1. Flag/vote to close the question if it's off-topic
2. Upvote an existing answer if it's useful
3. Post a new (and ideally better) answer

---

As for why it is not closed, we don't close questions even though they are very old/almost irrelevant as of now *as long as they are on-topic*. It might not help you and me specifically, but there's still someone out there who might get helped ;)

Otherwise, for this particular question, it might be edited to generalize the issue to any volume/notification system that is similar to the Galaxy Ace Duos 6802, so it would still be relevant until now (despite the minuscule amount of such devices/ROMs having this issue).